# F# data access and EF migrations

Tags: entity-framework, f#, entity-framework-migrations

I have been using F# for some time, and really liking it.

I want to use type providers for data access, but would love to have entity framework migrations.

Can I use EF migrations without entity framework? I am fine with writing migration code by hand, hopefully in F#.

Answer (score 4):

In the case where you want to use EFCore, it's possible to isolate only the migrations in a C# project with [MigrationsAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects).

For example in a `DbContext` module:

```
let setupOptions (optionsBuilder: DbContextOptionsBuilder) =
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(
        "Host=localhost;Database=mydb;Username=postgres;Password=postgres",
        fun opt -> opt.MigrationsAssembly "MyProject.Data.Migrations" |> ignore)
    |> ignore
```

Services configuration:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext.MyDbName>(DbContext.setupOptions)
```

CLI:

```
dotnet ef migrations add CreateFoo -p ./MyProject.Data.Migrations -s ./MyProject.Api -v    
dotnet ef database update -p ./MyProject.Data.Migrations -s ./MyProject.Api -v
```

There is also a work in progress project to support F# design-time:
https://github.com/bricelam/EFCore.FSharp

Answer (score 3):

F# type providers imply that there is already external data source i.e. they are inherently "Db First". Using EF Code First only to automatically generate migrations is not the best idea, I recommend plain SQL and some tools to keep track of migrations such as dbup. 
I [answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546947/1553641) in details in similar but bigger question.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use EF migrations without using EF in your app. Create a separate project and [use Code First migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621).

I'm not aware that the migrations scaffolding feature supports F#. Either suffer with C# for migrations or translate the code yourself?

Comment: EF generated migrations work with POCO model classes we create. As I am using F# type provider, I don't create model classes. I need the ability to easily rollback my database schema, when needed. I need EF migrations to work similar to node package db-migrate.