# F# type providers vs C# interfaces + Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, f#, type-providers

The question is very technical, and it sits deeply between F# / C# differences. It is quite likely that I might’ve missed something. If you find a conceptual error, please, comment and I will update the question.

Let’s start from C# world. Suppose that I have a simple business object, call it `Person` (but, please, keep in mind that there are 100+ objects far more complicated than that in the business domain that we work with):

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and I use DI / IOC and so that I never actually pass a `Person` around. Rather, I would always use an interface (mentioned above), call it `IPerson`:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    int PersonId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The business requirement is that the person can be serialized to / deserialized from the database. Let’s say that I choose to use Entity Framework for that, but the actual implementation seems irrelevant to the question. At this point I have an option to introduce “database” related class(es), e.g. `EFPerson`:

```
public class EFPerson : IPerson
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

along with the relevant database related attributes and code, which I will skip for brevity, and then use Reflection to copy properties of `IPerson` interface between `Person` and `EFPerson` OR just use `EFPerson` (passed as `IPerson`) directly OR do something else. This is fairly irrelevant, as the consumers will always see `IPerson` and so the implementation can be changed at any time without the consumers knowing anything about it.

If I need to add a property, then I would update the interface `IPerson` first (let’s say I add a property `DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }`) and then the compiler will tell me what to fix. However, if I remove the property from the interface (let’s say that I no longer need `LastName`), then the compiler won’t help me. However, I can write a Reflection-based test, which would ensure that the properties of `IPerson`, `Person`, `EFPerson`, etc. are identical. This is not really needed, but it can be done and then it will work like magic (and yes, we do have such tests and they do work like magic).

Now, let’s get to F# world. Here we have the type providers, which completely remove the need to create database objects in the code: they are created automatically by the type providers!

Cool! But is it?

First, somebody has to create / update the database objects and if there is more than one developer involved, then it is natural that the database may and will be upgraded / downgraded in different branches. So far, from my experience, this is an extreme pain on the neck when F# type providers are involved. Even if C# EF Code First is used to handle migrations, some “extensive shaman dancing” is required to make F# type providers “happy”.

Second, everything is immutable in F# world by default (unless we make it mutable), so we clearly don’t want to pass mutable database objects upstream. Which means that once we load a mutable row from the database, we want to convert it into a “native” F# immutable structure as soon as possible so that to work only with pure functions upstream. After all, using pure functions decreases the number of required tests in, I guess, 5 – 50 times, depending on the domain.

Let’s get back to our `Person`. I will skip any possible re-mapping for now (e.g. database integer into F# DU case and similar stuff). So, our F# `Person` would look like that:

```
type Person =
    {
        personId : int
        name : string
        lastName : string
    }
```

So, if “tomorrow” I need to add `dateOfBirth : DateTime` to this type, then the compiler will tell me about all places where this needs to be fixed. This is great because C# compiler will not tell me where I need to add that date of birth, … except the database. The F# compiler will not tell me that I need to go and add a database column to the table `Person`. However, in C#, since I would have to update the interface first, the compiler will tell me which objects must be fixed, including the database one(s).

Apparently, I want the best from both worlds in F#. And while this can be achieved using interfaces, it just does not feel the F# way. After all, the analog of DI / IOC is done very differently in F# and it is usually achieved by passing functions rather than interfaces.

So, here are two questions.

1. How can I easily manage database up / down migrations in F# world? And, to start from, what is the proper way to actually do the database migrations in F# world when many developers are involved?
2. What is the F# way to achieve “the best of C# world” as described above: when I update F# type `Person` and then fix all places where I need to add / remove properties to the record, what would be the most appropriate F# way to “fail” either at compile time or at least at test time when I have not updated the database to match the business object(s)?

Comment: I *think* the answer to both questions is to use EF in a C# library project. The F# type providers are really nice for small databases and projects. The tools are not there yet for F# type providers to handle the schema migration of "100+ objects far more complicated" across a big team.

Comment: I'm just learning about this myself so I can't give a full or even a good answer but the advice from my current resource is: "If you *must* use EF, I recommend creating a C# layer for your entity model and accessing that from F#." - [Isaac Abraham](https://www.manning.com/books/get-programming-with-f-sharp). Btw, excellent, well-written question!

Comment: `which completely remove the need to create database objects in the code: they are created automatically by the type providers` if only! That was the promise of ORMs too. That never works though. That's why people talk about the [object-relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch). Objects or records, an *application's* schema/type-system is seldom appropriate as a database schema and vice versa.

Comment: The database isn't an implementation detail of the application, in fact it's often the *opposite* with the database outliving the app. Most of the time, the database serves *multiple* apps. Even in the same application, the database serves *multiple* use cases that appear as different DbContexts and mappings. EF Code First and Database Migrations themselves would fail in such a scenario.

Comment: F# type providers are at the lighter end of ORMs, similar to microORMs like Dapper.  There are no schemas and migrations there, just queries that get automagically mapped to objects. The records returned can be read-only for all anyone cares, the microORM isn't trying to track changes.

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos has mentioned, you are suffering from an impedance mismatch. You cannot get around this mismatch, instead embrace it. TPs are an option if you see the DB upgrade as separate. Upgrade the schema as 1st story, domain as 2nd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I easily manage database up / down migrations in F# world?
>   And, to start from, what is the proper way to actually do the database
>   migrations in F# world when many developers are involved?

Most natural way to manage Db migrations is to use tools native to db i.e. plain SQL. At our team we use [dbup](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dbup/) package, for every solution we create a small console project to roll up db migrations in dev and during deployment. Consumer apps are both in F# (type providers) and C# (EF), sometimes with the same database. Works like a charm.

You mentioned EF Code First. F# SQL providers are all inherently "Db First" because they generate types based on external data source (database) and not the other way around. I don't think that mixing two approaches is a good idea. In fact I wouldn't recommend EF Code First to *anyone* to manage migrations: plain SQL is simpler, doesn't require "extensive shaman dancing", infinitely more flexible and understood by far more people.
If you are uncomfortable with manual SQL scripting and consider EF Code First just for automatic generation of migration script then even [MS SQL Server Management Studio designer can generate migration scripts for you](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1723/auto-generate-change-scripts-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-for-tables/)

> What is the F# way to achieve “the best of C# world” as described
>   above: when I update F# type Person and then fix all places where I
>   need to add / remove properties to the record, what would be the most
>   appropriate F# way to “fail” either at compile time or at least at
>   test time when I have not updated the database to match the business
>   object(s)?

My recipe is as follows:

- Don't use the interfaces. as you said :)

> interfaces, it just does not feel the F# way

- Don't let autogenerated types from type provider to leak outside thin db access layer. They are not business objects, and [neither EF entities are](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/389198/155708) as a matter of fact.
- Instead declare F# records and/or discriminated unions as your domain objects. Model them as you please and don't feel constrained by db schema.
- In db access layer, map from autogenerated db types to your domain F# types. **Every usage of types autogenerated by Type Provider begins and ends here.** Yes, it means you have to write mappings manually and introduce human factor here e.g. you can accidentally map FirstName to LastName. In practice it's a tiny overhead and benefits of decoupling outweigh it by a magnitude.
- How to make sure you don't forget to map some property? It's impossible, F# compiler will emit error if record not fully initialized.
- How to add new property and not forget to initialize it? Start with F# code: add new property to domain record/records, F# compiler will guide you to all record instantiations (usually just one) and force you to initialize it with something (you will have to add a migration script / upgrade database schema accordingly).
- How to remove a property and don't forget to clean up everything up to db schema. Start from the other end: delete column from database. All mappings between type provider types and domain F# records will break and highlight properties that became redundant (more importantly, it will force you to double check that they are really redundant and reconsider your decision).
- In fact in some scenarios you may want to preserve database column (e.g. for historical/audit purposes) and only remove property from F# code. It's just one (and rather rare) of multitude of scenarios when it's convenient to have domain model decoupled from db schema.

**In Short**

- migrations via plain SQL
- domain types are manually declared F# records
- manual mapping from Type Providers to F# domain types

**Even Shorter**

Stick with Single Responsibility Principle and enjoy the benefits.

Comment: offtopic, if your database is MS SQL I recommend to look at this Type Provider: https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/  it works only with MS SQL and requires to write SQL quries or stored procs manually i.e. it's not really ORM but level of compile time safety is nothing like I felt before. When it compiles it usually works, sometimes I don't even bother to run before moving on.

Comment: thanks, I already use it and I do that manual mapping from type provider type to F# types in a single project. This comes naturally in F# as we absolutely don't want these mutable, nullable structures escape into the world of pure functions :)